# Named Query doesn't return entity persisted in another thread/transaction a minute ago

Tags: multithreading, hibernate, jpa, spring-batch

Basically I have a spring batch job:

```
<batch:job>
  <batch:step>unimportant</batch:step>
  <batch:step id="process">
     <batch:tasklet task-executor="processPool">
        <batch:chunk reader="reader" writer="writer" commit-interval="1" processor="processors">
        </batch:chunk>
     </batch:tasklet>
  </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

Nothing special here, reader is `JpaPagingItemReader` with `pageSize=4` and writer is `JpaItemWriter`.

Here is my processor:

```
public class MyProcessor implements ItemProcessor<MyItem, MyItem> {
    
    private static final Logger LOG = ...

    @Autowrired
    private ExternalService externalService;

    @Override
    public MyItem process(MyItem item) {
        String alternativeId = externalService.getAltId(item); 
        item.setAlternativeId(alternativeId);
        LOG.info("Updated item is {}", item);
    }
}
```

Then I have another thread which listens for jms queue and when the message arrives there with alternative id it does the following

```
public onMessage(String alternativeId) {
    MyItem item = entityManager.createNamedQuery("findByAlternativeId", MyItem.class).setParameter("alternativeId", alternativeId);

    if (item == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Item not found for altId=" + alternativeId);
    }
    // do something else
}
```

Named query is as simple as `select item from MyItem where item.alternativeId =:alternativeId`

The problem is in the logs I see:

> 10:10:30 INFO "Updated item is MyItem[id=1, alternativeId=ALT.15]"
>
> 10:10:40 ERROR Item not found for altId=ALT.15

If I then go to a database to check for an entry, it's there and have a correct alternative id. Moreover the issue is quite rare and doesn't get reproduced easily. Also I do see TransactionalTemplate.execute in the stacktrace of exception.

I use hibernate 4, spring 4.
I don't have any second hibernate cache defined, I do have order_inserts,order_updates,batch_size defined. DB is oracle 12c.

Any thoughts why this may happen?

Comment: Can you do a small test, and add an EntityNotFoundException catch and check on it it the you can load any row from this table?, and also activate hibernate jpql/sql debug info in order to see query what are being executed

Comment: Is there any possibility that your first transaction doesn't finish when the second query are being performed ?, and can you post the full stacktrace of the exception where you see the transactionalTemplate?

Comment: @karelss ok, I will prepare a test but it will take some time. I can't show you the production stacktrace for all the security reasons, so there is not much to say until I somehow reproduce that by recreating similar code. Transactions is the first thing which came to my mind, but I don't believe 10 seconds or even 5 were not enough to complete transactions, database is rather small...

Comment: i've said transations but i'm thinking more in threads, if you use resource_local transactions the context is bounded tho the thread so if your thread doesn't end either your transaction